# How do I elegantly import an Excel file into Sql Server via a Coldfusion HTML form?

Tags: sql-server, excel, coldfusion

Does anyone have an elegant suggestion for how to get the contents of an Excel spreadsheet into SQL Server via a web form? I need to allow our clients to upload modest amounts of structured data, and I need that data to ultimately reside in a sql table. I really can't expect the clientele to produce anything but an Excel file, but I could require that it be an xlsx.

The web app is written in Coldfusion; it doesn't need to be able to handle huge numbers of simultaneous requests, but I don't want to consider some sort of server-side batch job processing or shunt the user to an asp.net page (which is what we are doing now).

Any recommendations (or examples of how others are successfully doing this) would be appreciated. Due to the sensitivity of the data, we really can't do anything to compromise the security of the web or sql servers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using CF9, then you could easily use the cfspreadsheet tag too.  I mention this one specifically because Shawn's link did not (presumably due to its being relatively new on the CF scene).  Here's the livedoc link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html

For full use, I would create a web form with a standard file upload field.  On the backend handling the form submission, get a copy of the file with

```
<cffile action="upload" destination="uploaded.xls".....>
```

Then use:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" query="myExcelData" src="uploaded.xls" ...>
```

At which point, your spreadsheet content will be available as a query object.  You can then loop over this query, running insert queries into your sql server each time you loop.  That should do it.

Comment: I had to wait until we could install CF9 to try this out, but it worked fantastically! This was a great recommendation; I hadn't even considered it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the most notable options to help point you in the right direction; choose what you are most comfortable with (Source: [Charlie Arehart](http://carehart.org/cf411/#excel)).

- [CFXL](http://cfxl.riaforge.org/)
- [JXLS](http://www.mattjanell.com/uploads/enclosures/jxlsdemo.zip)
- [CFX_Excel](http://www.masrizal.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=idea.download_detail&ProductID=cfx_excel)

My personal recommendation is to go the [CFX_Excel](http://www.masrizal.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=idea.download_detail&ProductID=cfx_excel) route. Although a commercial product, it will grant you the most functionality/flexibility of the options listed.

Comment: I'm uncertain of why this was down-voted, but if it was due to a lack of physical code examples, it would seem a bit counter-intuitive to provider examples for each of the several dozen options listed on Charlie's page--rather than allowing the OP to choose the one that best suits their needs. I've therefore added a recommendation to clear the OP a more direct path.

Comment: No doubt Charlie's resources are valuable, but should that link ever cease to function, this answer is absolutely useless.

Comment: @Al Mm, noted, the CF community often comes to assume certain resources will remain permanent. I'll update my answer.